# NIntegrate into NDSolve with variable integrand

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I need to solve an integral into an ordinary differential equation like this:

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == x + NIntegrate[y[r], {r, 1,x}], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Note that now the variable in the integrand is not constant. How can I solve it?

Comment: @MMM in the solution you deleted you have `y'[0] == 0`, should be `y'[1] == 1` then it comes out right.  (the integral is zero at x=1 ..)

Comment: @george2079 I didn't get alert for your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Numerical solution:

```
solution = 
NDSolve[{D[y[x], x] == x + f0[x], y[0] == 1, f0'[x] == y[x], f0[1] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 1}];
```

[Symbolic solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134428/34008) from @rewi **(Works only in MMA 11.0 and above.)**:

```
sol = -((1 + E^2 + E^(1 - x) - 2 E^(2 - x) - 2 E^x - E^(1 + x))/(1 + E^2));
```

.

```
Plot[{Evaluate[y[x] /. solution],sol}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thin}, {Blue, Dashed}}, PlotLegends -> {"numeric", "symbolic"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I like this straightforward solution with numerics. :)

Comment: In short: to use `NDSolve[]` efficiently, reformulate your integro-differential equation as a set of ODEs.

Comment: actually, `DSolve` gives the analytic result  with this form with v10.1 (10.1 does not support @rewi 's integro-differential form)

Answer (score 6):

Mathematica 11.01

```
eq = {y'[x] == x + Integrate[y[r], {r, 1, x}], y[0] == 1};
sol = First@DSolve[eq, y, x]
```

[image]

```
eq /. sol // Simplify
{True, True}
```